# The whole screen scrolls, but you need only one widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Please tell me. I have a scrollable list with languages. But at the moment I have the whole page scrolling. How can I make it so that only the list with languages ​​scrolls, and everything else (search bar, buttons - are fixed in one place)? I attached a screenshot below where I showed which part I need to scroll, and not the whole screen.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 178),
              const BackStepWidget(text: 'Select Language'),
              const SizedBox(height: 30),
              SizedBox(
                width: size.width,
                child: Card(
                  color: constants.Colors.greyDark,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 16),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 20),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                                child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: constants.Colors.greyLight,
                                  hintText: 'Search',
                                  hintStyle:
                                      TextStyle(color: constants.Colors.white),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.search,
                                    color: constants.Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_voice,
                                      color: constants.Colors.white),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  )),
                            )),
                            const SizedBox(width: 14),
                            const Text('Cancel',
                                style: constants.Styles.smallBookTextStyleWhite)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 14),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
                        child: MediaQuery.removePadding(
                          context: context,
                          removeTop: true,
                          child: ListView.separated(
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            separatorBuilder: ((context, index) => Divider(
                                height: 2,
                                color:
                                    constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2))),
                            itemCount: language.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 9, bottom: 10),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    language[index],
                                    style: constants
                                        .Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    language[index],
                                    style: constants
                                        .Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              // ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that you have `SingleChildScrollView` at the top. This is the reason why everything scrolls.

Deeper in the three you have `ListView.separated` with `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and `shrinkWrap: true`.

ListView is scrollable by itself, but that neverScroll parameter prevents in from doing it. Also shrinkwrap might not be a good thing here to, but that's a different story.

Remove `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` and get rid of `SingleChildScrollView`.

You might end up with content overflowing issue, but this can be fixed somewhat easily.

UPD: To solve vertical overflow: put your `ListView` inside `Flexible`.

Simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('widget.title'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: TextFormField(initialValue: 'Search box here'),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('$index'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I encountered the problem of content overflow in the normal view and in the view when I open the keyboard. How to solve the overflow problem?

Comment: updated the answer, tldr: put listview into Flexible

Comment: Also avoid using `shrinkWrap: true` if not necessary because it forces to render all the items in advance, which is bad for performance.

Comment: And if I don't have ListView but only ListView.separated, and I put it in Flexible, I still have an error

Comment: If possible, you can specify in my code where you want to place Flexible. Just I tried on ListView.seperated - doesn't work. I will be grateful for help

Comment: `ListView.separated` is the same thing as `ListView` but a bit more convenient. I tried your code and it seems that the reason you are still getting this error is that you have too many nested Columns. My advise is to refactor it a bit: create one `Column` that will contain three parts: title, search box and your list. First two should have defined height, the third one should be flexible (to fill the remaining space). Also try to separate parts of the code into different widgets or methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243623/discussion-between-obywan-and-max-zubko).